# Clion failed and got clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1, but it work using clang++

Tags: cmake, clang, c++14, clion

I am new to C++ and now I am studying Class. I am using the book "Guide to Scientific Computing in C++" and using Clion(for Mac) to write my code and test them. Yesterday I encountered a weird problem that I couldn't run my code in Clion but it worked by using clang++ file1 file2 file3.

In Clion I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "ComplexNumber::GetRealPart() const", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [2] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/2.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/2.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [2] Error 2
```

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef COMPLEXNUMBERHEADERDEF
#define COMPLEXNUMBERHEADERDEF

#include <iostream>

class ComplexNumber
{
    private:
        double mRealPart;
        double mImaginaryPart;
    public:
        ComplexNumber();
        ComplexNumber(double x, double y);
        double CalculateModulus() const;
        double CalculateArgument() const;
        ComplexNumber CalculatePower(double n) const;
        ComplexNumber& operator=(const ComplexNumber& z);
        ComplexNumber operator-() const;
        ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber& z) const;
        ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber& z) const;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output,const ComplexNumber& z);

        double GetRealPart() const;
        double GetImaginaryPart() const;
        friend double RealPart(const ComplexNumber& z);
        friend double ImaginaryPart(const ComplexNumber& z);
        ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber& z);
        ComplexNumber(double real);
        ComplexNumber CalculateConjugate() const;
        void SetConjugate();

        //not mandatory, but useful for exercise 6.1.7
        ComplexNumber operator*(const ComplexNumber& z) const;

};
```

Because till now, I don't need to use all functions so I only defined functions that I would use, like those:

```
#include "ComplexNumber.hpp"


ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber()
{
    mRealPart = 0.0;
    mImaginaryPart = 0.0;
}
// 6.1.1
double ComplexNumber::GetRealPart() const
{
    return mRealPart;
}

double ComplexNumber::GetImaginaryPart() const
{
    return mImaginaryPart;
}

// 6.1.2
double RealPart(const ComplexNumber& z)
{
    return z.GetRealPart();
}

double ImaginaryPart(const ComplexNumber& z)
{
    return z.GetImaginaryPart();
}

// 6.1.3
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &z)
{
    mRealPart = z.mRealPart;
    mImaginaryPart = z.mImaginaryPart;
}

//6.1.4
ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double real)
{
    mRealPart = real;
    mImaginaryPart = 0.0;
}

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(double x, double y)
{
    mRealPart = x;
    mImaginaryPart = y;
}

//6.1.5
ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::CalculateConjugate () const
{
    double conjugate_real = mRealPart;
    double conjugate_imaginary = -mImaginaryPart;
    ComplexNumber conjugate(conjugate_real, conjugate_imaginary);
    return conjugate;
}

//6.1.6
void ComplexNumber::SetConjugate()
{
    double minus = -mImaginaryPart;
    mImaginaryPart = minus;
}

// overload operator =
ComplexNumber& ComplexNumber::operator=(const ComplexNumber &z)
{
    mRealPart = z.mRealPart;
    mImaginaryPart = z.mImaginaryPart;
    return *this;
}

// overload operator +
ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator+(const ComplexNumber &z) const
{
    ComplexNumber w;
    w.mRealPart = mRealPart + z.mRealPart;
    w.mImaginaryPart = mImaginaryPart + z.mImaginaryPart;
    return w;
}

// overload operator *
ComplexNumber ComplexNumber::operator*(const ComplexNumber &z) const
{
    ComplexNumber w;
    w.mRealPart = (mRealPart * z.mRealPart) - (mImaginaryPart * z.mImaginaryPart);
    w.mImaginaryPart = (mRealPart * z.mImaginaryPart) + (z.mRealPart * mImaginaryPart);
    return w;
}
```

In my main.cpp, I writed like this to test my Class:

```
#include "ComplexNumber.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ComplexNumber test(1.0);
    cout << test.GetRealPart() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and for cmakelist, I wrote this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(handin2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(1 ComplexNumber.cpp)
add_executable(2 main.cpp)
add_executable(4 test.cpp)
```

Then I got the linker error, but it did work by using clang++ main.cpp  <.cpp>.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand CMake. Each add_executable command tells CMake to create a new executable which contains the code from the given files. So you have created three executables, each contains the code of one .cpp file.

The CMake command which is equivalent to your commandline is:

```
add_executable(executeable_name main.cpp <.cpp>)
```

Or with the concrete names:

```
add_executable(executeable_name main.cpp ComplexNumber.cpp)
```

Comment: Oh yes! It works for me now. Thank you for your reminder and sorry for this naive error :(